# STOMP in Spring WebSocket Lost Connection before connected

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp

I try to connect with server by STOMP, but I get Lost Connection message with any specific information.

WebSocket config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queve")
            .setClientLogin("quest")
            .setClientPasscode("quest");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {


    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    public void greeting(HelloMessage message){
        System.out.println("Wiadomosc: " + message.getName());
    }

    @SubscribeMapping({"/helloSub"})
    public HelloMessage handleSubscription() {
        HelloMessage outgoing = new HelloMessage();
        System.out.println("SUB");
        outgoing.setName("Jas");
        return outgoing;
    }

}
```

js script:

```
 var sock = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/BuyMyTime/hello");
    var stomp = Stomp.over(sock);
    var payload = JSON.stringify({'name':'Jasiek'});
    stomp.connect('quest', 'quest', function(frame){
        //stomp.send("/hello", {}, payload);
    });
```

When i send get http://localhost:8080/BuyMyTime/hello i receive: Welcome to SockJS! so Socket is fine but when i try stomp.connect i receive:

```
Opening Web Socket... stomp.js:134:99
Web Socket Opened... stomp.js:134:99
>>> CONNECT
login:quest
passcode:quest
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

"Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:8080/BuyMyTime/hello" stomp.js:134:99
```

Is there any missing config i did not included? How can I get more info about this connection lost? Please for any help.

**Update (Aug 28 2016)**

I add this dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and now get:

```
<<< ERROR
message:Broker not available.
content-length:0
"Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:8080/BuyMyTime/greeting"
```